# How scientifically created new language could be helpful to all of humans?

Tags: language

It is common in the world for all of us to use English in the STEM field. But for non-native English speakers who are having a tough time to explain certain concepts using that language, Why can't the scientific community could develop one common language to address this problem? This will also serve as the world language and the language of all.

Comment: And then *everyone* can have problems explaining concepts translated into your synthetic language?  Other than that, this is probably off topic, since it doesn't seem to be about world building as such, but more of a real world question.

Comment: Such a new language was developed [over a century ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto), and was formally adopted for scientific communication in 1921. You can judge it's helpfulness for yourself.

Comment: How would a created language improve the situation regarding non-native speakers?

Comment: David Bohm developed the [Rheomode](https://jongoodbun.wordpress.com/what-does-rheomode-mean/) with David Peat a while ago. The struggle of explaining the whole philosophy of the thing tends to put people off though.

Comment: then everyone would have to learn a new language. why not just make it easier for a big chunk of the population, and have the rest learn the language, instead of making every one learn a language?

Comment: @michaelgriffin good idea, let's adopt Chinese as our new lingua franca for science. It's has the most native speakers, therefore, it has *the least* amount of people who need to learn it as a secondary language.

Comment: that'd be nice! if only America actually made it required to learn a fucking language, and only if the fucking Chinese government wasn't so authoritarian, and DYING. @VLAZ

Comment: I don't fully understand why you would think that learning Fancy New Scientific Language would be easier than learning English. You may also want to consider that there are many many many books and movies in English, vs. none yet in Fancy New Scientific Language, so that learners have a ready made vast library of usage examples which they can use to improve their language.

Comment: I am not anyway against English. I am grateful that at least already one such language exists which, not all of but most of the humans could speak and understand. If I have offended any English speaking people, I am sorry. All of the existing world languages have advantages and disadvantages, my question was about how could a language that constructed from scratch efficiently help people learn and understand science better and boost works related to science. @AlexP

Comment: My native language is not English. You did not offend me in any way. I was asking simply because I don't see how reading science in a different language could help.

Answer (score 11):

Inevitable XKCD:

[image: XKCD standards]

People have of course tried this sort of thing in the past... there are no shortages of old conlangs with utopian fantasies attached. Esperanto is perhaps the classic, which has a [whole raft of issues](http://jbr.me.uk/ranto/index.html), some or more of which have contributed to its failure to take over the world. There are older, weirder things like [Volapük](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volap%C3%BCk), and no shortage of newer weirder things none of which have caught on and often involve their own [weird internal political struggles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_between_Lojban_and_Loglan). Ultimately, in the real world, no-one cares. In your fictional worlds you can handwave that differently, of course. Heinlein used loglan in *The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress* as a technical language, though everyone still conversed with each other in naturally evolved languages.

With regards to English, its importance in many STEM fields is relatively new. German was important until not so long ago, when WW2 rather reduced its importance in academic papers. Go back a little further and there was a lot of Latin about, but not so much these days. There's no guarantee that English will retain its place in the sun forever, but it will almost certainly be replaced for pragmatic reasons ("everyone speaks X, and we're bored of using this weird old language instead") rather than utopian ideals of creating a wonderful new language that everyone will use instead.

Of course, you may handwave it otherwise in your works.

---

As a possible counter argument, at least one fictional setting has suggested that having a truly common language was very much a bad thing, and referred to the periods in the setting's past where single language dominated as the "monolingual stases".

This comes from a stronger interpretation of the [Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity), suggesting that language was the vehicle of thought and as such the language you use to think effectively constrains the range of thoughts you might have. *1984*'s [Newspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak) was built around this idea (to hamper the minds of citizens to the point where opposition to the status-quo was literally unthinkable), as was Iain. M. Banks' [Marain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Culture#Language) though the latter was intended to liberate rather than constrain. John Meaney's *Nulapeiron Sequence* took the view that homogeneity was bad, and the planners of its societies took steps to ensure that there was always a multitude of language to ensure that a greater breadth of ideas would arise naturally in those societies.

Answer (score 2):

It has been tried before. Esperanto was an artificial language created in 1887. Its purpose was to promote world peace by having a universal second language.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto